# Quick proof verification of limit of a finite measure.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

I'm a little unsure if what I've done is correct, so I just need a quick verification.

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and $F_\mu : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ with $F_\mu(x) = \mu((-\infty, x])$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Find the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}F_\mu(x)$.

I've already shown that the function is increasing. But I'm unsure if what I've done to show what the limit is, is correct. Here's what I've done.

Let $(x_n)$ be an increasing sequence with no upper bound. Let $(I_n)$ be a decreasing sequence of intervals, where $I_n = (-\infty, -x_n]$. Then

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} F_u(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mu(I_n) = \mu\left(\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}I_n\right) = \mu((-\infty, -\infty)) = \mu(\emptyset) = 0$$

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is incomplete.

It lacks a proof that from the data:

- $\mu$ is finite,
- $I_1\supseteq I_2\supseteq I_3\supseteq\cdots$

we are allowed to conclude that: $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(I_k)=\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n)$$

Note that the sets $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n,I_1\setminus I_2,I_2\setminus I_3,\dots$ are disjoint with: $$I_1=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(I_{n}\setminus I_{n+1})$$

From this we conclude that $$\mu(I_1)=\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(I_n\setminus I_{n+1})=\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\mu(I_n)-\mu(I_{n+1})\right)$$

In $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\mu(I_n)-\mu(I_{n+1})\right)$ we recognize the limit: $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\left(\mu(I_n)-\mu(I_{n+1})\right)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left[\mu(I_1)-\mu(I_k))\right]=\mu(I_1)-\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(I_k)$$

So confirmed is that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(I_k)$ exists and also that it satisfies:$$\mu(I_1)=\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n)+\mu(I_1)-\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(I_k)$$

Then our final conclusion is that $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(I_k)=\mu(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n)$$